# PSNR on live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming, videoquality

I need to measure quality of a live stream, and I was thinking of measuring PSNR. So I was wondering how can I run this test since it is a live stream, I do not have a refence stream or video. Should I look for a reference video of the same resolution and bitrate, like for example a Big buck bunny, and compare against It?

Thanks

Comment: PSNR compares a reference to result. Without a reference PSNR is not a thing.

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg-archive.org/PSNR-measure-td4684436.html